# Tag Questions with Linking Verbs

Tags: question-tags, linking-verbs

Only an auxiliary verb is repeated in tag questions. My question is which auxiliary verb should be used in the tag when the main verb of the sentence is a linking verb other than 'be'?

> 1. You look a bit sacred, don't you? Or, You look a bit scared, aren't you?
> 2. She seems happy, doesn't she? Or, She seems happy, isn't she?

Which version of the above ones is more correct and appropriate to use in a test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *You look a bit sacred, don't you?* Or, *You look a bit scared, aren't*
> *you?*
>
> *She seems happy, doesn't she?* Or, *She seems happy, isn't she?*

The usual rule is that if the anchor predicator is an auxiliary, select the same lexeme, otherwise select "do".

In your examples the predicators are not auxiliaries, but lexical "look" and "seem", so "do" is correct.

Comment: thank you for your wonderful answer.